# How to get date from calendar:datePicker and make an ajax call?

Tags: grails, calendar

I've added plugin calendar http://www.grails.org/plugin/calendar to my web app. I don't know how to handle change value event, get date and call ajax request to refresh some other part of the page that depends on this date. Where should I call controller/action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach an `onchange` listener to the element(s) that the calendar plugin stores the date/time in. You can use the [remoteFunction](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html) tag to generate the JavaScript function that makes the AJAX call. For example, if the time is stored in an element with id `foo`, the following will invoke the `myAction` action of `FooController` with the selected date sent as the value of the `currentDate` parameter

```
$('#foo').onchange = "${remoteFunction(action:'myaction', controller: 'bar'
        params:'\'currentDate=\' + this.value')}"
```